# Missing Return Statement Error java

Tags: java

```
public String getValue(int n) 
{
    if (n % ham == 0 || n % spam==0)
    {
        if(n % ham == 0 && n % spam == 0)
        {
            return "hamspam";
        }
        else if(n % ham == 0 && n % spam != 0)
        {
            return "ham";
        }
        else if(n % ham != 0 && n % spam==0)
        {
            return "spam";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Integer.toString(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: When inside a method you must specify a return path for all possible paths. In this case there exists a path where your three if/elseif conditions may all evaluate to false and no return path is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, we may conclude that if `n` is a multiple of `ham` or of `spam`, then either `n` is a multiple of both, or of exactly one of the two.  We can logically conclude that there is no way that inside the outer `if`, at least one of the 3 conditions inside will be `true` and a `return` will be executed.

But the Java compiler is not that smart.  It just sees no `return` past the last `else if` in the block, and concludes that there is an execution path that doesn't have a `return`, so it gives the compilation error.

Logically, if the first 2 conditions are `false`, given the outer `if`, the third condition must be true.

Replace

```
else if(n % ham != 0 && n % spam==0)
```

with

```
else
```

It is logically equivalent, and the compiler will also be satisfied that every execution path has a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getValue(int n) 
{
    if (n % ham == 0 || n % spam==0)
    {
        if(n % ham == 0 && n % spam == 0)
        {
            return "hamspam";
        }
        else if(n % ham == 0 && n % spam != 0)
        {
            return "ham";
        }
        else if(n % ham != 0 && n % spam==0)
        {
            return "spam";
        }

        // this return is missing
        return "something";
    }
    else
    {
        return Integer.toString(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first `if` statement, you need an `else` clause or a `return` value.

To elaborate, what if:

```
if (n % ham == 0 || n % spam==0) //is true

 if(n % ham == 0 && n % spam == 0) // is false
    {
        return "hamspam";
    }
    else if(n % ham == 0 && n % spam != 0) //is false
    {
        return "ham";
    }
    else if(n % ham != 0 && n % spam==0)//is false
    {
        return "spam";
    }
```